# Word for a casual performance (example: Bowie performing Heroes live in Berlin 2002)

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking unpretentious or unassuming, but they don’t quite capture the sentiment that I want to convey regarding this type of performance. Low-key works sort of in a slang way, but I know there is a more satisfactory word out there but I can’t remember it for the life of me.

Link of performance: https://youtu.be/bsYp9q3QNaQ

I’m referring to the way he performs and how he presents himself (the suit, lack of movement, etc.) while still delivering an amazing performance.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence showing how the word is to be used (per the SWR tag).

Comment: Like some stand-up comics (Bill Murray, Jack Dee,...), Bowie often adopts a ***deadpan / impassive*** presentational style.

Comment: I see an off-hand or impromptu performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**understated**
<sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>

presented or expressed in a subtle and effective way

*‘understated elegance’*

<sub>Source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/understated)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Compared to his famously glam rock performances, this is a **stripped down** performance.

> Drop Everything And Watch Taylor Swift's Stripped-Down Performance Of "Wildest Dreams"

https://youtu.be/OGDkg3QiJmk

It tends to refer to both the subdued musical arrangements and the performance together.

Answer (score 0):

He gave an **effortless** performance.

> *effortless*: ...
>
> 1.1: achieved with admirable ease.
>
> *Shorn of its string arrangement, Drake's incredible guitar playing and effortless melodic sense are all the more apparent.*
>
> SYNONYMS flowing, fluid, fluent, smooth, graceful, elegant, natural,
>   leisurely, easy

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/effortless)]